# TensorFlow - Setting some variables as `Trainable=False` vs passing variables to the optimizer?

Tags: python, tensorflow

To only train specific variables in TensorFlow, you can either pass a specific list to the optimizer to train, or you can set some variables as untrainable. Are there any benefits to choosing one method over the other (aside from ease of including/excluding variables)?

I could see it being possible that if a variable was set to `Trainable=False`, then the graph might be built differently (i.e. without gradient paths). I could see this potentially having an effect on efficiency. Is this the case? And, if it is, does it make any (noticeable) difference?

Also, are there any other "gotchas" to look out for when using one method over the other? For example, when passing variables to the optimizer, are there common global variables or such that might easily accidentally be missed? Any other things to note?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Both methods give the same graph. Optimizer by default takes variables from `GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES` collection, which is a Python list of variables created with `trainable=True`